# MahApps.Metro controls properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am making a WPF app for work using MahApps.Metro. I want to style and modify my tiles, the problem is the documentation is not very descriptive:

How to use the Tile

The following XAML will initialize a Tile control with its Title set to "Hello!" and its Count set to 1.

```
<controls:Tile Title="Hello!" 
               TiltFactor="2"
               Width="100" Height="100" 
               Count="1">
</controls:Tile>
```

There is no descitpions of things. Where do I get information like:
What is the tilt factor?
 What does count do?
What events are available?
How do I make my own style of tiles in app.xaml?

Regards

Comment: Look at their sample app [HERE](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/samples/MetroDemo/ExampleViews/TilesExample.xaml).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, it is a definitely a big step forward but it doesn't solve the problem, I don't know where to find a list of these properties for each control with comments.

Comment: You can download the entire `Mahapps` source code from the same location, for any and all components, sample apps and everything.

Comment: Thanks for that, I actually went through the source code, it wasn't that scary:) thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Once you open the project in VS, you can use the **Object Browser** window to easily navigate through namespaces, classes, properties, methods, events, etc, without going to the source code.

Comment: @jstreet I'm sorry about the currently not good explained Tile control. I'm currently working on a new updated documentation which still is a lot of work...

Comment: @punker76 you guys do great work, so don't be sorry.

Comment: @punker76 Exacly the library is amazing:) I am not yet ready for proper software development but I could Help out with documentation, how do I sign up?